# Get Values out of a Hash

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a Ruby script to scrape the App Store for reviews. I've made a request and get back all the information I need. It is returned in the following format:

```
{
"userReviewList": [{
    "userReviewId": "userID",
    "body": actual_review,
    "date": "2016-03-09T15:10:00Z",
    "name": "Laurean C",
    "rating": 5,
    "title": "Best banking app on my phone!",
    "voteCount": 0,
    "voteSum": 0,
    "viewUsersUserReviewsUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/reviews?userProfileId=profileID",
    "voteUrl": "https://userpub.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZUserPublishing.woa/wa/rateUserReview?userReviewId=appID",
    "reportConcernUrl": "https://userpub.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZUserPublishing.woa/wa/reportAConcernSubmit?cc=us",
    "reportConcernExplanation": "Provide more details about this review of 'app name'. The author of the review will not be able to see this report.",
    "customerType": "Customers",
    "reportConcernReasons": [{
        "reasonId": "0",
        "name": "Choose One"
    }, {
        "reasonId": "1",
        "name": "This review contains offensive material"
    }, {
        "reasonId": "8",
        "name": "This review is not a review or is off-topic"
    }, {
        "reasonId": "9",
        "name": "I disagree with this review."
    }, {
        "reasonId": "7",
        "name": "My concern isn't listed here."
    }]
}, ...
```

It's a large list so I only included what one review would look like. The response comes back as a string, and after calling `JSON.parse(rawResponse.body)` I have a variable called `response` which should have the data in it.

When I print out `response.class` I get told it's a hash, so I've tried the following to get the actual data out:

```
puts response[:userReviewList]

key = 'userReviewList'
puts response[key.to_sym]
```

Both of these return nothing. Am I doing something wrong to get a hash value out? I'm using the gem rest-client if that makes any difference.

Comment: Try `response['userReviewList']`.

Comment: Just remove the `to_sym` from `response[key.to_sym]`, since your response contains string as keys and not symbols. `response[key]` will work.

Comment: ndn that works wonderfully. If you add your comment as an answer I'll accept it once it lets me. I can't believe something so simple was the issue I was having.

Comment: @BillL, lets just close the question.

Comment: The question is likely to be a duplicate of a duplicate of a ...

Answer (score 1):

JSON keys become simple strings:

```
require 'json'

json = <<EOJSON
  {
      "userReviewList": [{
              "userReviewId": "789021517",
              "body": "My shopping experience has bla bla bla",
              "date": "Apr 16, 2013",
              "name": "Djdannybhhhhh",
              "rating": 5,
              "title": "Awesome!",
              "voteCount": 0,
              "voteSum": 0,
              "viewUsersUserReviewsUrl": "https://xxxxxx.com/us/rexxxws?usxxxxileId=xxxxxx",
              "voteUrl": "https://xxxxxx.com/us/rexxxws?usxxxxileId=xxxxxx",
              "reportConcernUrl": "https://xxxxxx.com/us/rexxxws?usxxxxileId=xxxxxx",
              "reportConcernExplanation": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.",
              "customerType": "Customers",
              "reportConcernReasons": [{
                      "reasonId": "0",
                      "name": "Choose One"
                  }, {
                      "reasonId": "1",
                      "name": "This review contains offensive material"
                  }, {
                      "reasonId": "8",
                      "name": "This review is not a review or is off-topic"
                  }, {
                      "reasonId": "9",
                      "name": "I disagree with this review."
                  }, {
                      "reasonId": "7",
                      "name": "My concern isn't listed here."
                  }
              ]
          }
      ]
  }
EOJSON

response = JSON.parse(json)
puts response['userReviewList'].first['userReviewId'] #=> 789021517
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the keys are strings. You can get to the value using:

```
puts response['userReviewList']
```

or if you're on Rails:

```
response.symbolize_keys!
puts response[:userReviewList]
```